# Block inheritance of static function in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance

A small test case :

```
class A
  def self.print
    puts "Hello A"
  end
end


class B < A
end

A.print
B.print
```

This outputs :

```
Hello A
Hello A
```

I would like to block the inheritance of the `print` function defined in `class A`. Is it possible?

Output wanted :

```
Hello A
`<main>': undefined method `print' for B:Class (NoMethodError)
```

I found `private_class_method` but it's not exaclty what I'm looking for as it fails on `A.print` call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class A
  def self.print
    puts "Hello A"
  end

  def self.inherited(klass)
    class << klass
      undef :print
    end
  end
end

class B < A
end

A.print
# Hello A

B.print
# private method `print' called for B:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Edited my answer. My previous approach actually removed the method from `A`, too. Also, I used `remove_method`, which does not work in the child class. `undef` however works, so kudos to @Huluk.

Answer (score 3):

```
class B < A
  class << self
    undef print
  end
end
```

Declaring a method in a `class << self` block is the same as declaring it prefixed with `self.`.
It also allows for the behavior that you want.